# List of tables error while using \usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}

Tags: tocloft

I have a problem with my document which gives me the following error in Overleaf:

```
\l@table #1#2->\ifnum \c@lotdepth 
                                  >\z@ \vskip \cftbeforetabskip {\leftskip \...
l.1 ...le}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Test}}{4}
                                                  %
```

I have figures, subfigures which work fine and show up as I want them to be. However, I now wanted to insert my first table and I get this error and it does not show up in my list of tables. I read up and could identify that it has to with my subfigure package. How can I solve the problem without changing the package as I need it for my other figures?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,tabularx,graphicx}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}

% Formatting ToC
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{\centerline{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}

%% Adjust spacing between number and title in ToC
\advance\cftsecnumwidth 1em\relax
\advance\cftsubsecindent 1em\relax
\advance\cftsubsubsecindent 1em\relax

%% Adjust dots in ToC & LoF
\renewcommand\cftdotsep{1}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{1}
\makeatother

% Formatting LoF
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\section*{LIST OF FIGURES}}
\newcounter{lofdepth}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{3}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subfigure}

% Formatting LoT
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\section*{LIST OF TABLES}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\section*{LIST OF TABLES}}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage

\section{Nice0}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=8pt,position=bottom}
    \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\subcaption[Test]{\bf Test}}\hfill
    \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\subcaption[Test2]{\bf Test2}}
    \caption[SuperTest]{{\bf Test} \\Histogram of (a) Test and (b) most common Test sample.} \label{figure:Test}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\section{Nice1}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption[Test]{\bf Test} \blindtext
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|} \hline\hline
Ice Cream Store & Location & How to Get There \\ \hline
Toscanini’s & Central Square & Just walk! \\
Herrell’s & Harvard Square & Red Line \\
J.P. Licks & Davis Square & Red Line \\
Ben \& Jerry’s & Newbury Street & Green Line \\ \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\label{table:Test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but `\label{table:Test}` should better be placed inside of the corresponding `table` environment. Also, do not use `\bf` to make your captions bold. `\bf` is deprecated and if you want all your captions to be bold, add `font=bf` to the options of the `caption` package instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work for me but don't ask me why.

```
% subtocprob.tex  SE 540609

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,tabularx,graphicx}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[list=true]{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}

% Formatting ToC
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage%[subfigure]
  {tocloft}
%\usepackage{subfigure}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{\centerline{TABLE OF CONTENTS}}

%% Adjust spacing between number and title in ToC
\advance\cftsecnumwidth 1em\relax
\advance\cftsubsecindent 1em\relax
\advance\cftsubsubsecindent 1em\relax

%% Adjust dots in ToC & LoF
\renewcommand\cftdotsep{1}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{1}
\makeatother

% Formatting LoF
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\section*{LIST OF FIGURES}}
%\newcounter{lofdepth}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{3}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subfigure}

% Formatting LoT
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\section*{LIST OF TABLES}}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\section*{LIST OF TABLES}}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\clearpage

\section{Nice0}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=8pt,position=bottom}
    \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\subcaption[Test]{\bf Test}}\hfill
    \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\subcaption[Test2]{\bf Test2}}
    \caption[SuperTest]{{\bf Test} \\Histogram of (a) Test and (b) most common Test sample.} \label{figure:Test}
\end{figure}

\clearpage
\section{Nice1}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption[Test]{\bf Test} \blindtext
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l||c|c|} \hline\hline
Ice Cream Store & Location & How to Get There \\ \hline
Toscanini’s & Central Square & Just walk! \\
Herrell’s & Harvard Square & Red Line \\
J.P. Licks & Davis Square & Red Line \\
Ben \& Jerry’s & Newbury Street & Green Line \\ \hline\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\label{table:Test}

\end{document}
```

I deleted any reference to `subfigure` and also commented out the `\newcounter{lofdepth}` line.

Comment: My code is in general probably not very clean. Your suggestion fixes the problem on my side as well! Thank you @Peter Wilson